# python socket listener high load

Tags: python, sockets

I have a threaded Python listener designed to read, validate and write the data into files.

So far I have it limited to handle only 20 concurrent connections but now I need it to handle more, hundreds.. maybe 1000.

The exchange of data is a series of read writes between the client and server:
hello, username, password, category, multi-line text, bye

There is a 1 second sleep between each operation.

This is an example code to show the way it was designed.

```
  def handler(csock, caddr):
    while 1:
      # read hello
      # send welcome

      # read username
      # send true/false

      # read password
      # send true/false

      # read payload
      # send true/false

      # read bye
      # send bye

      # close connection
      # write data to file

      # Example how read and send are done
      inc = csock.recv(1024)
      csock.send(out)

  serversocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
  serversocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
  serversocket.bind(('', 50005))
  serversocket.listen(20)

  while 1:
    csock, caddr = serversocket.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=handler, args=(csock, caddr,)).start()
```

**My questions:**

Is Python capable to operate without problems with up to 1000 concurrent connections?

If my code design solid enough for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python threads are locked by something called the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). What this means is that any threads spawned by a python interpreter are all still run under one `main` thread. They cannot be multithreaded (at least not in vanilla python). So in your case, while you are spawning a thread per connection, they are still running sequentially.

One workaround is the `multiprocessing` module of python.

Python also has some [default modules](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) to help accomplish your task.

^^^These map directly to your idea of assigning a thread/process to each client.

Also consider looking at [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), a 3rd party python library.

If on linux ( I think it maps to windows/mac as well), consider looking up the `select` statement in python. It (basically) checks a large list of connections and returns the ones with waiting input/output.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a whole lot of information here. A helpful thing to know would be the average expected size of incoming text. One might have a several-line text file that is still barely 1 KB, which means that the max your computer would have to handle at any given time is still under 1 MB. I think that with average internet speed you could handle up to 30 line text files before you start getting really lag-y. You could compensate for this lag by measuring how long it takes each step to complete and then subtract that from time.sleep. With fast internet speed you could handle at least 70 lines at a time, by my calculations. Do you plan on encrypting username and password?

Comment: Username and password are encrypted before transmission with pre-shared secret. The payload size can be up to 50MB. Most of the time around 1-25K. Server has gigabit connection according to data center. After many years with them I cannot complain internet to be slow.

Comment: Then this should work. When operating at maximum string size and user capacity your computer may crash, but it will only be rather slow for the majority of the time. If you are using one computer just for this purpose you should be all set, but obviously make sure you max out your RAM to handle all of that information at once.